# iOS - How to set up an Custom class to the control programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uislider

Am having and UISlider that i have created programmatically i would like to customise the UISlider appearance so i user used some UISlider custom class.

Is it possible to set up an custom class to the UISlider control programmatically without storyboard

[image]

Comment: describe what problem you've got? It would better if you put some code here

Comment: Do you want to programatically a UISlider instead of using storyboard? Please let me know

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JMMarkSlider *firstSlider;
in this they have import the UISLider in Storyboard and they setup the custom class JMMarkSlider in storyboard(Please refer the image). 

In my code dont have storyboard so i cant able to set up the custome class to the UISlider control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

`#import "JMMarkSlider.h";`

Then declare a property like a normal property declaration:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JMMarkSlider *firstSlider;
```

Then Declare the frame and add to View as for a normal UI element:

```
 self.firstSlider=[[JMMarkSlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
```

Add any DataSource and Delegate to the `ViewController.h` file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i will like this

Comment: I have tried like this but i can get the default slider not the expected custom slider

Comment: for creating the IBOutlet connection we need a storyboard right with out storyboard how do we connect this and added the custom class in the property area (refer the image)

Comment: I used a library called richTextEditor and I initialized it in the exact same way

Comment: dont create an IBOutlet just declare it as a property and later on in your -(void)loadView define the frame as I have done in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127099/discussion-between-md-ibrahim-hassan-and-vignesh).